# JBoss - Keep the .war extension and not the exploded one

Tags: deployment, jboss, war

Is there a way to keep the .war extension when deploying on JBoss server ?
I tried this parameter : auto-deploy-exploded="false" in the standalone.xml but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`auto-deploy-exploded` is used to Controls whether exploded deployment content should be automatically deployed by the scanner without requiring the user to add a .dodeploy marker file. Setting this to 'true' is not recommended for anything but basic development scenarios, as there is no way to ensure that deployment will not occur in the middle of changes to the content.